# Python Regex pattern findall

Tags: python, regex, greedy, findall

The reg expression below

```
get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<(.+)>", t)
st = "xyx<ab>xy x<bc> xyx<cd>xyxy xx<de> xyx <ef>x y<fg><gh>y"

print(get_tags(st))
```

expected output was

```
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh']
```

even though the pattern is not greedy (no '*' used?), the expression gives the output

```
['a>xyx<b>xyx<c>xyxyxx<d>xyx<e>xy<f><g']
```

What is the problem in the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.+` is greedy by default. You need to add `?` reluctant quantifier next to the `+` to do a non-greedy match.

```
get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<(.+?)>", t)
```

OR

```
get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<([^<>]+)>", t)
```

`[^<>]+` negated character class which matches any character but not of `>` or `<` one or more times.

```
>>> get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<(.+?)>", t)
>>> st = "xyx<ab>xy x<bc> xyx<cd>xyxy xx<de> xyx <ef>x y<fg><gh>y"
>>> print(get_tags(st))
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh']
>>> get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<([^<>]+)>", t)
>>> print(get_tags(st))
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know to find only letters between `< >` you could also use

```
get_tags = lambda t: re.findall(r"<(\w+)>", t)
```

as regex.  that would only search for `[A-Za-z]` between `< >` and since there are spaces an some different between the brackets in your example. this would also work.